# !! 0xc01a00d !! aka Vista won't boot

Tags: windows-vista, boot, updates

Answer: Parts of the hard drive are corrupted. All of my user's code was checked in, so I'm just going to format the box.

One of my users has an HP DV5-1235dx laptop running Windows Vista Professional x64. Last night, our WSUS server pushed out a few updates including "Security Update for Windows Vista for x64-based Systems (KB960859)". When we try to boot the laptop today, a black screen with white text comes up displaying:

> xxx/169894 (something)

Where xxx increments rapidly and something is some dll or registry key.

Eventually that stops and the screen displays

> ! 0xc01a00d !! 35566/169894 (\Registry\Machine\COMPONENTS\DerivedDat...)

No other computers that received this update are displaying the same error.

So far I've tried running CHKDSK off of HBCD. It repaired a thing or two, but the computer still doesn't boot. I tried repairing the Windows install from the Vista CD, but I get a black screen with white text displaying something along the lines of:

> 0  No Emulation System Type 00
>   1  No Emulation System Type 00
>   Select one of the above

Booting in Last Known Good Configuration doesn't work. Booting in Safe Mode freezes at

> Loading Windows Files
>   [snip]
>   Loaded: \windows\system32\drivers\crcdisk.sys
>   Please wait...

My next step is trying to boot Safe Mode with Command Prompt and try to run rstrui.exe. While I do that, does anybody have any guidance?

Edit: Booting into Safe Mode with Command Prompt will not work. See Booting in Safe Mode above.

Edit 2: I managed to boot from the Vista DVD. I ran the system repair, and now I get a black screen with white text saying:

> ! 0xc0000034 !! 290/169894 (_0000000000000000.cdf-ms)

Edit 3: I ran the system repair again, and it attempted to repair my hard drive. It failed.

> Problem Signature:
>   Problem Event Name: Startup Repair V2
>   Problem Signature 01: External Media
>   Problem Signature 02: 6.0.6001.18000.6.0.6001.18000
>   Problem Signature 03: 4
>   Problem Signature 04: 196611
>   Problem Signature 05: CorruptVolume
>   Problem Signature 06: NoBootFailure
>   Problem Signature 07: 0
>   Problem Signature 08: 0
>   Problem Signature 09: unknown
>   Problem Signature 10: 1168
>   OS Version: 6.0.6002.2.2.0.256.1
>   Locale ID: 1033

Answer: Parts of the hard drive are corrupted. All of my user's code was checked in, so I'm just going to format the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parts of the hard drive are corrupted. All of my user's code was checked in, so I'm just going to format the box.

Answer (score 2):

I think you would be right to try the System Restore next from the recovery console.

I have quite often had problems running the GUI from the recovery console, so here is an [alternative method](http://www.myfixes.com/articles/system) if you also have similar problems.  I have used it and it works great if you know that the registry or system files are to blame.  Just skip down to part B.  It is based on the Microsoft article [here](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=KB;EN-US;Q307545&ID=KB;EN-US;Q307545).

EDIT (following info about failing to access recovery console)

1. Can you get into the BIOS?  If so, try resetting the BIOS to factory settings.
2. Try removing RAM a stick at a time, if possible and more than one in the laptop, to rule out bad memory.  This has been reported as a cause of this exact problem.

Comment: How can I get to the recovery console if I can't boot from the Vista DVD? I'm still getting the No Emulation System Type message.

Comment: Do you have an XP CD to hand?

Comment: I'm going to pull one off MSDN. Does it have to be 64 bit?

Comment: Yuk, seems as though a different CD will not help - save your bandwidth.  Failing getting into Safe Mode with command prompt, how many sticks of RAM does it have?  One cause I found was bad RAM.  Not a very helpful error message in that case.

Comment: The different CD did not help; you are correct.

This machine has 2 x 2GB sticks. I ran the memory tester that comes with Hiren's Boot CD and the memory passed. Still, I'll try booting with only one stick and then the other.

Comment: Pulling neither one nor the other stick helped. However, I did notice something new: Vista would start booting, then a stop error (BSoD) would flash on the screen briefly (very briefly, maybe 10ms). I put in the Vista CD and selected 0 at the "No Emulation System Type 00" screen, and it booted.I'm running the system repair now.

Comment: No such luck. Whole new error.

Comment: Can you now get into the gui or recovery console/command prompt to try the system restore now?

Comment: Yes, I can. I tried the steps in the alternative method you suggested, but I failed. I updated my original question with some additional information. Looks like it's a bad hard drive, perhaps?

Comment: That's confirmed. I just ran chkdsk again, and there's a lot of "Index entry [foo] in index [bar] of file [baz] is incorrect." followed by "CHKDSK cannot continue in read-only mode."

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you "select one of the above"?

It's supposedly not an error - just a bios prompt for the boot type (floppy emulation or regular modern cd boot process normally though yours looks a bit weird).

Additions: Verify that the Vista DVD actually works, try to get or burn another to rule out problems with it.

As I think you stated you did boot some kind of CD perhaps the PC can't read DVDs (if it's an old one)?

Now would be a good time to get out that spare USB dvd-rom to test with as well - or if the laptop is relatively modern, try booting Vista from an USB stick.

Comment: It puts me into the menu where I have the option to Boot Normally, Boot the Last Good Configuration, boot in Safe Mode, boot in Safe Mode with Command Prompt, and boot Safe Mode with Networking. None of which get me anywhere useful.

Comment: Then have you verified that the dvd is actually bootable? Try getting another one... if it still won't boot, I'd say the drive's busted or the boot options in BIOS setup aren't set up correct?

Comment: I've booted off that disc before, and it's relatively unscratched. I'll check it out.

Comment: I managed to boot off the CD and run the system repair. Different error now. I'll try the system restore.